# VBA Close Java Alerts Popups with name "Message from webpage"

Tags: excel, vba

Im having a problem dealing with the java scripts alerts..

I am able to navigate and enter data in the webpage but when selecting different item to update a modal alerts displayed..

How can I click the OK button tru VBA?

Any help please...

Here is the code in the webpage i think firing when i select an item triggering the alert..

This is what i see in the HTML scripts:

```
function onUpdatedShowAlertTS(varControl) {


if (varControl == "ddlProjectStatus") {
var varconfirm = document.getElementById('ctl00_Tabs_pnlCaptureTSMetrics_CaptureTSMetrics_hdnReleaseStatusConfirmation');
if (varconfirm.value == "true") {
var varControlId = document.getElementById('ctl00_Tabs_pnlCaptureTSMetrics_CaptureTSMetrics_ddlProjectStatus');
var value = varControlId.options[varControlId.selectedIndex].innerText;
alert('Release status is reset to ' + value + ' successfully and validation status is Pending.');
document.getElementById('ctl00_Tabs_pnlCaptureTSMetrics_CaptureTSMetrics_hdnReleaseStatusConfirmation').value = "false";
}
}


if (varControl == "ddlReleaseName") {
var varconfirm = document.getElementById('ctl00_Tabs_pnlCaptureTSMetrics_CaptureTSMetrics_hdnReleaseNameConfirmation');
if (varconfirm.value == "true") {
alert('Release status and and validation status is reset successfully.');
var isReadOnlyStatus = '0'
if (!(isReadOnlyStatus == 1)) {
document.getElementById('ctl00_Tabs_pnlCaptureTSMetrics_CaptureTSMetrics_hdnReleaseNameConfirmation').value = "false";
document.getElementById('ctl00_Tabs_pnlCaptureTSMetrics_CaptureTSMetrics_btnSaveValidate').disabled = false;
}
}
}
```

This is my code:

```
ieDoc.getElementById("ctl00_Tabs_pnlCaptureTSMetrics_CaptureTSMetrics_hdnConfirmationforReleaseChange").Click
ieDoc.getElementById("ctl00_Tabs_pnlCaptureTSMetrics_CaptureTSMetrics_hdnConfirmationforReleaseChange").setAttribute "value", "true"
ieDoc.getElementById("ctl00_Tabs_pnlCaptureTSMetrics_CaptureTSMetrics_hdnConfirmationforReleaseChange").setAttribute "type", "hidden"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One immediate solution would be to use the `SendKeys` function.

```
Application.SendKeys "n"          ' Send the latter "n" to the dialog

Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}"    ' Send ENTER to the dialog
```

You can find more information on [SendKeys here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa202943%28v=office.10%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks.. It works ... I just have a few clarifications... Where does the "n" came from the source? What is the use of it? Though, I know that using sendkeys is not reliable... do we have other options to consider?

Comment: I used "n" in case the dialog was a "Yes"/"No" prompt, hence sending it an "n" would select "No".  I have found SendKeys to work most of the time.  Your other option might be to create a Web client in VBA by automating Internet Explorer or by using [WinInet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385331%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Your client could do the task you are performing manually.