# Detect and Click on a javascript alert with vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to go through webscraping results from a website and only problem is when I input an invalid input it throws an java alert box which i am not able to overcome using the VBA code.

Code is given below

```
Sub TIN_VERIFY_TN()
Dim ie As Object
Dim form As Variant, button As Variant
Dim pannumss As Characters
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")

With ie

.Visible = True
.Navigate ("http://www.tnvat.gov.in/tamil/Tinverification.aspx")
Do While ie.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

countsss = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))
For X = 2 To countsss
ie.Document.getelementsbyname("txt_tngst").Item.Value = Cells(X, 1)

 ie.Navigate "javascript:__doPostBack('LinkButton2','')"
 
  Do While ie.Busy Or Not ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Loop

  Cells(X, 2) = ie.Document.getElementById("txtName").innerText

  ie.Navigate ("http://www.tnvat.gov.in/tamil/Tinverification.aspx")
  Do While ie.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

  Next
  End With
  Set ie = Nothing
End Sub
```

---

Have figured this is the event that is creating the msgbox

```
<Script language='javascript'>alert('Invalid TIN No');</script><script language='javascript'>document.getElementById('txt_tngst').focus();</script></form>
        </body>
    </HTML>
```

How can I know when alert has been triggered and how I should close the alert once it appears?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486847/close-javascript-alert-using-vba-automation

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18075762/vba-close-java-alerts-popups-with-name-message-from-webpage?rq=1

Comment: Could you please provide any valid `TIN No` for testing?

Comment: Hi sorry for the delayed reply was not in town for the weekend. Have given two TIN's 33543227809 (invalid one) & 33623682307(valid one). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to prevent scripts execution by `.execCommand "stop"` before readystate becomes complete:

```
Sub TIN_VERIFY_TN()

    Const READYSTATE_UNINITIALIZED = 0
    Const READYSTATE_LOADING = 1
    Const READYSTATE_LOADED = 2
    Const READYSTATE_INTERACTIVE = 3
    Const READYSTATE_COMPLETE = 4

    Dim ie As Object
    Dim form As Variant, button As Variant
    Dim pannumss As Characters
    Dim cnt As Long
    Dim x As Long
    Dim a

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        cnt = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))
        For x = 2 To cnt
            .Navigate "http://www.tnvat.gov.in/tamil/Tinverification.aspx"
            Do While .busy Or Not .readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop
            .document.getElementsByName("txt_tngst").Item.Value = Cells(x, 1)
            .document.parentWindow.execScript "__doPostBack('LinkButton2','')", "javascript"
            Do While .readyState < READYSTATE_INTERACTIVE: DoEvents: Loop
            .document.execCommand "stop"
            Do While .busy Or Not .readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop
            a = Array(.document.getElementById("txtName"))
            If TypeName(a(0)) <> "Null" Then Cells(x, 2) = a(0).innerText
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Omega. Thanks for the code. The code does not seem to be executing the submit function now. Basically the following code is now not loading the result   .document.parentWindow.execScript "

Answer (score 0):

Tried a lot and could figure out one way to get things done
Create a vbscript i.e. *.vbs file - add wait time and entery code for passing Enter key save it on local pc
call this vbscript before you click button or fill up the respective field...
in my case i was getting alert / msg on clicking button.